# VirtualBox won't save network settings for snapshot

Tags: virtualbox

I'm trying to access my MAMP hosts from VirtualBox, and problem seems to be that VirtualBox won't save my network settings.

Here's what I do:

Open up the settings for the snapshot and change the network settings to "Host-only Adapter", and press "OK".

[Like this (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkK1V.png)

But when I open up the settings right after pressing "OK" it still shows "NAT" as the network setting.

[Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/mcjxCzh)

Is this a bug, or am I missing out on something here?

Comment: BTW, I've been using [this guide](http://www.justinmarsan.com/blog/hacks/2012/11/15/mac-osx-virtualbox-windows-localhost-mamp/) for all the other settings.

Answer (score 4):

I used to have this problem and it was by luck I solved it!
The trick is to go to 'Machine' menu and click 'Discard saved state'. This error occurs because Virtualbox cannot change anything with the VM running.
:)